# Are these correct?

Tags: word

大家好！

Are these correct?

1.两个桥墩相距20米。
两个桥墩相隔20米。

2.我家离学校相距一小时。
我家离学校相隔一小时。

3.学生要以课本为主，回归于课本。
学生要以课本为主，回归课本。

造的句子对吗？

谢谢！！！！

Comment: Better just ask what is the difference between 相距 and 相隔 and drop #3

Comment: 不是的，你说错了。。。。。。。。。

Comment: Funnily enough there's a very similar question on WordReference (https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/相距一小时.3835536/#post-19598812). Regarding sentence 2, I think I have to agree with SuperXW's answer there: "一小时 is a period of time. 相距/相隔 refers to distance. They don't match."

Comment: 相距/相隔 mostly refers to distance,  but 距 (length away from) and  隔 (apart by ) can also be used for a time, as if there is a distance between the start and the end of a period of time, Example: 距離奧運會開幕尚有一個月；奧運會每隔四年舉行一次

Comment: How about 相 差 which Cantonese speakers like to use?

Comment: @ Wayne Cheah  No, we don't use 相差 for the travel distance between locations. We use 相差 for comparing height/ length,  weight, quantity, or quality. Example: 二人身高相差有一米多; 二人體重相差近三十公斤; 兩軍人數相差無幾; 徒弟與師傅的水準相差極遠; 東岸時間和西岸時間相差了四小時.  But we don't say 兩地距離相差了一千公里

Comment: 这部影片从开始拍摄到上演相距只有十个多月的时间。这部影片从开始拍摄到上演相隔只有十个多月的时间。 对吗？

Answer (score 1):

### English Editon

> 两个桥墩相距20米。 两个桥墩相隔20米。

相距：相互间距离。
相隔：彼此间距离。

相距 and 相隔 are set of synonyms. It can be used to describe the distance of space, time, etc. Their word meanings are very close. In some [online dictionaries](http://xh.5156edu.com/html5/89099.html), they are even used 相隔 to explain the 相距, so in most cases, they are completely interchangeable. They are not interchangeable only in some idioms or fixed collocations. (Like 阴阳相隔)

These two sentences describe the spatial distance between two piers, so the use of 相距 and 相隔 is correct.

> *我家离学校相距一小时。 *我家离学校相隔一小时。

描述距离的时候，可以使用相距或相隔

You can use 相距 or 相隔 to describing distance, but you must use specific length units but not just a time unit.

If you want to use the time to describe distance, you must specify the means of transportation used.

These two sentences describe the distance from home to school in the unit of time, without specifying the means of transportation used, so they are both wrong.

You can write like this:

- 我家离学校相距一公里。 我家离学校相隔一公里。
- 我家到学校乘车需要一小时。 我家到学校乘自行车需要一小时。

> 学生要以课本为主，回归于课本。 学生要以课本为主，回归课本。

Both of these sentences are correct, but the more common way of writing is the latter.

---

### Chinese Edtion

> 两个桥墩相距20米。 两个桥墩相隔20米。

相距 与 相隔

相距：相互间距离。
相隔：彼此间距离。

相距与相隔是一组近义词，可以用来形容**空间**、**时间**等的距离。他们的词意义十分接近，在一些[在线字典](http://xh.5156edu.com/html5/89099.html)里，甚至在用相隔来解释相距，所以在大部分情况下是完全可以互换的，只有在一些成语或固定搭配中才不能互换。（如阴阳相隔）

这俩个句子在描述两个桥墩之间的空间距离，所以使用相距和相隔都是正确的。

> *我家离学校相距一小时。 *我家离学校相隔一小时。

描述距离的时候，可以使用相距或相隔，但是必须要使用具体的长度单位，而不能只使用时间单位。
如果要使用时间来描述距离，必须指明所使用的交通工具。

这俩个句子在使用时间单位描述家到学校的距离，而没有指明所使用的交通工具，所以他们都是错误的。

你可以这样写：

- 我家离学校相距一公里。 我家离学校相隔一公里。
- 我家到学校乘车需要一小时。 我家到学校乘自行车需要一小时。

> 学生要以课本为主，回归于课本。 学生要以课本为主，回归课本。

这俩个句子都是正确的，不过平时比较常见的写法是后一种。

Comment: 字典的例句：这部影片从开始拍摄到上演相距只有十个多月的时间。为什么可以？          
                      相隔两个月没有见面。

Comment: @jinglingmen Sorry for this, I will check more and edit it soon.

Answer (score 0):

Correct, 相距：相互间距离。= 相隔：彼此间距离。

There is a slight difference between these sentences:

学生要以课本为主，回归于课本。 学生要以课本为主，回归课本。

回归于 - return to

回归 - return

The difference in grammar is clear in English, but in Chinese, the difference is in the style of writing.

回归于XX - 用於白話文體

回归XX - 適用於文言文體(古文)

Since the leading phrase is in 白話文體, thus the following phrase should agree with the lead and use 回归于课本. But, as the writing in 混合體(白話文夾雜文言文) is common these days, 回归课本 is fine also.